# Core Bluetooth determines the peripheral device as unique

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

How does core bluetooth determine the new peripheral device as unique?

I have devices. Each device has services. Each service has characteristics.

When we test bluetooth-based app, it appears, that some (different) devices have same uids ( `peripheral.identifiers` ).

I think that it happens because of lack of advertising information on device ( devices don't advertising services and they coalescing into one peripheral.identifier )

I suppose that services can't differ (could/should be the same) among devices, the same story with characteristics.

So, which info should be enough for bluetooth to determine that new peripheral device is unique?

**Our experiment**

We have two devices, one with name 'oldboy' and another with name 'newone'.
Also, we have same services on each device ( services has same structure and same uuids. services uids and characteristics uids are the same across all devices )
Names are differ between devices.
Sad, devices don't advertising services and app scan for all services passing nil to appropriate method `scanServices: options:` instead of services uids array. It could be done but it doesn't help in background and seems very bad for energy efficiency.

Server send information about all devices that could be found.
We suppose, that uids are not generated by system and we can hardcode uid of devices and differ devices on this characteristic ( `peripheral.identifier` )

One iDevice have tested app with perihperal device called 'oldboy' very long.
And this iDevice should work with another device called 'newone'. 
As it started to scan, it found an device with `name = 'newone' and 'peripheral.identifier = peripheral(oldboy).identifier'`.

Again, it can't be true, so, we disconnect all devices except 'newone' and restart experiment. Ok, same issue.
And final check was on interaction. We connect to device ('newone') and try to send command to it. Nothing happens. But when we try to send command to 'oldboy' device, we win!

I dive into this issue and found that connected 'newone' device identifier  somehow equal to 'oldboy' device identifier.

It happens in didDiscoverPeripheral handler. So, before connection system recognize 'newone' peripheral device as a 'oldboy' peripheral device ( their peripheral.identifier are equal )

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

    // take peripheral info ?
    // check that peripheral identifier is valid for us

    BOOL identifierIsOk = YES;

    DDLogDebug(@"we found! peripheral: %@ ", peripheral);
    DDLogDebug(@"and data: %@",advertisementData);

    if (identifierIsOk) {
        // put peripheral into dictionary storage and try to connect and discover services and characteristics
        [self centralManager:central safeConnectToPeripheral:peripheral];

    }
}
```

**BUG**

Finally, we solved our troubles.
We found that MAC addresses are same on different devices!
Afterwords, I want to add this article as [core bluetooth understanding tool](https://trungvo.wordpress.com/2015/05/19/notes-on-apple-core-bluetooth-peripheral-id/)

Comment: Are you sure that they are different devices? Your app may read the advertisement data (piece by piece) various times and that should trigger the didDiscoverPeripheral: various times and make you create that you saw differents devices.

Comment: @Larme, I updated question, please, look at experiment description